# Transform coordinates from one Kinect 3D space to another

Tags: c#, matlab, transform, kinect, kinect-sdk

Im currently tracking a Skeleton Joint real world coordinate in multiple Kinects.

But these coordinates are expressed in relation to each Kinect coordinate space.

What i want to do is elect one of the Kinects as the "Master" and have all others transform their coordinates to this Master Kinect's coordinate space. I made a paint image to illustrate:

[image]

From what i ve seen on the internet this involves heavy math. Is there any ready code/library with functions that do this? Or even matlab code? Im using C# and Kinect SDK, but this doest not limits the language of an possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you can just use transformation matrices to achieve this? If you know the rotation and translation necessary to get from "Slave" to "Master" Kinect, you can just apply it to your point cloud detected by the "Slave Kinect".

Comment: Do you know any method/algorithm that does this?

Comment: I already told you the method. Just use the rotation matrix and add a translation vector to your axes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/geometry/transformationsrev2.shtml

Comment: Thank you, i was able to do it using the rotation matrix and translating.

Comment: Diedre: can you provide any details about what functions did you use? I'm facing the same problem with Kinect v2 and the MS provided examples don't really help.